# Organzing Data in EEPROM

Tags: embedded, binary-data

I have a 64KB EEPROM, organized as 128-byte pages, on my board which talks to an AT Mega 1281. The board also has a SD Card slot and is capable of copying over some configuration files onto the EEPROM (which acts as the internal memory). Due to the nature of the board, only two types of files are needed - one is known as the Circuit Data and the other is Location Data - both are binary files.

Up until now, I had just split the EEPROM into two 32K halves and wrote the Circuit Data in the top half and the Location Data in the bottom half. Both files also have a 25 byte header. I copy the header in the last pages of the files respective half i.e. the page starting at address 0x7F80 has the Circuit Data file's header and the address starting at 0xFF80 has the other header. The data is always going to be of fixed width so that makes random access quite easy.

My question is, is there a better, simpler, way to organize data in an EEPROM? At the moment, I don't even store the length of the data as it's not really needed. But I'm thinking it might add an another step of safety if I do include that in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better? It depends. Simpler? Really not. It depends how strong is your "always". How much do you believe yourself that the files will be always of fixed length? The fact that you are asking this question probably means some doubts. Keep in mind [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Microcontroller development is still an area where unecessary features are a direct threat to the solution stability. Having a data length in the header would be useful if you want to make your EEPROM access more generic. But then again, generalization for two files is an overkill.

Second thought: rather than introducing file lengths which you actually don't need, i would like to know why you store the file headers at the opposite side of the respective memory chunk. A "header" is to me something what needs to be read before the file itself. You could save one transfer of the reading address to EEPROM.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, in any embedded project, simplest solution is the best. Your way to organize storage is simple, and looks like it meets all your requirements.

Any attempt to "improve" or "optimize" this solution will lead to more complicated code and will increase probability of making bug in it. So keep all your engineering solutions as simple as possible. If there will pop new requirements, you always can find new simple solution for them. Don't do any premature optimizations.